# Return type of operator = in C++

Tags: c++

I just have a clarification to make. Say for example I want to override the operator =. From what I've read, this should return a REFERENCE to the object. And as what I've read from another source, a Reference is just an alternate name to the object. So could I do this?

```
MyObject MyObject::operator =(const MyObject &o2) {
    //insert processing code here
    return *this;
}
```

rather than this?

```
MyObject& MyObject::operator =(const MyObject &o2) {
    //insert processing code here
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You could but it makes little sense.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious why so? A reference is just another name of the object right?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel he's not returning a pointer (he's returning `*this` instead of `this`).

Comment: Because you're returning a temporary from a function that is typically expected to return a reference to the object on the left hand side of the expression.

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case, you return a copy of `*this`, not a reference to `*this`. So you should stick to the second case. There is a big difference between those 2 cases, especially for types that are "expensive" to copy.

Comment: Therefore, the first one is inefficient since it would take up a lot of memory. Is my understanding right sir?

Comment: It would take memory and time to construct the copy, and most of the time the copy is useless. So yes, your understanding is correct.